# Getting exception Error(near "INDEX": syntax error) in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm a newbie in Database.
I'm trying to create some tables but it fails with error "near 'INDEX' : syntax error".
Here is my codes to generate tables :

```
        try {
        using( SqliteCommand cmd = _db.CreateCommand() ) {

            // create words table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE words";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = 
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words(" +
                    "word_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                    "word_eng VARCHAR(128)," +
                    "PRIMARY KEY(word_id)" +
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // create word_classes table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE word_classes";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = 
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS word_classes(" +
                    "word_class_id INTEGER," +
                    "word_class_name VARCHAR(50)," +
                    "PRIMARY KEY(word_class_id)" +
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // create meanings table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE meanings";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = 
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meanings(" +
                    "meaning_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                    "meaning VARCHAR(100)," +
                    "word_class_id INTEGER," +
                    "PRIMARY KEY(meaning_id)," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(word_class_id) REFERENCES word_classes(word_class_id)" + 
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // create word_meaning_realationship table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE word_meaning_realationship";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS word_meaning_realationship(" +
                    "word_id INTEGER," +
                    "meaning_id INTEGER," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(word_id) REFERENCES words(word_id)" +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(meaning_id) REFERENCES meanings(meaning_id)" +
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // create decks table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE decks";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS decks(" +
                    "deck_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                    "deck_name VARCHAR(128)," +
                    "deck_version INTEGER," +
                    "PRIMARY KEY(deck_id)" +
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // create deck_word_relationship table
            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE deck_word_relationship";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deck_word_relationship(" +
                    "deck_id INTEGER," +
                    "word_id INTEGER," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(deck_id) REFERENCES decks(deck_id)," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(word_id) REFERENCES words(word_id)" +
                    ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    } catch( SqliteException ex ) {
        Debug.LogError( "DBError : " + ex.ToString() );
    }
```

It would be very appreciated if you check my other codes to create table, as I'm a totally newbie in database and mysql, and am not very confident of my codes :)

** updated **
I decided not to think about indexing for now. I updated my codes that have small errors that made my code not working. But if you tell me how to apply indexing for me, I will make it as a correct answer after application. Thanks for helps of you guys.

Comment: what is your database? Sqlite or mysql?

Comment: My database is Sqlite.

Comment: then why why tagged as `mysql`?

Comment: I thought they are the same;aren't they? Isn't Sqlite based on mysql?

Comment: if you think so, run the statement on ide like [sqliteadmin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). there are many syntax changes between mysql and Sqlite

Comment: Oh nice. It is good to know there are differences. I will fix the tags. Thanks Damith!

Comment: I guess someone fixed tags for me? thanks to him^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create Table first and then add the index like below

```
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS word(" +
                    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "word VARCHAR(128))";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_word_word ON word(id)";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks man! I 'll try that tomorrow mornin g and let you know!( 12 am in my country )

Answer (score 1):

You have different errors in your statements:

- Spelling of the word `REFERENCES` for foreign keys. You always wrote this with double "F", this is wrong. Don't know if this is a typo.
- In creation of table `meaning`, you have missed a `NOT` for checking if table exists: this should be `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`
- In creation of table `deck`, you want to create an index on the field `text`, but this field does not exists. So you should create the index on the field `name` or something different

After fixing all this errors, I could execute all of statements on a plain MySQL database (did not test your code, just tested the statements directly on the database).

Comment: Still the error exists though. The error is issued for the first create table query and i don't know why.

Comment: Oh buy the way, the same query works in mysql bench but not in C# sqlite

Comment: My answer is based on your MySQL tag (which you have fixed actually). Anyway I think that my suggestions are also ok für you :)

Comment: Thank you I applied all the small errors you suggested. But about indexing, I simply took out indexing parts from my code. It was about optimization and I didn't want to think about it now. But I appreciate your help man :) I updated my code as well.